# How does Chubby allow fine-grain locking on clients using coarse-grain locking?

Tags: distributed-computing, locks

I was reading the [Chubby paper from OSDI 2006](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/chubby-osdi06.pdf), and had a question regarding coarse and fine-grained locking. The paper describes at-length why they opt for only supporting coarse-grained locking, however at a certain point in the paper they mention it is straightforward for clients to implement fine-grained locking.

Here is the excerpt:

> Chubby is intended to provide only coarse-grained
> locking. Fortunately, it is straightforward for clients to
> implement their own fine-grained locks tailored to their
> application. An application might partition its locks into
> groups and use Chubby’s coarse-grained locks to allocate
> these lock groups to application-specific lock servers.
> Little state is needed to maintain these fine-grain locks;
> the servers need only keep a non-volatile, monotonicallyincreasing acquisition counter that is rarely updated.
> Clients can learn of lost locks at unlock time, and if a
> simple fixed-length lease is used, the protocol can be
> simple and efficient.

Is Chubby's role in client-implemented fine-grained locking simply the consensus around which application-server is responsible for the lock group associated with a fine-grained lock? And then inside the lock group server, there would be an acquisition counter to keep track of state?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it means although Chubby is for coarse-grained lock, we still can use Chubby for find-grained lock occasions, if we separate the locks which require  coarse-grained and fine-grained. For example, there userService and productService, userService update user info, while productService update product info. Maybe product info update require a fine-grained lock, so we can deploy a specific Chubby cluster to handle it.

There's a paper titled 'Hierarchical-Chubby' to make Chubby more scalable.